# Is it possible to display superscript characters in the alert() dialog?

Tags: javascript, unicode, character, alert, superscript

Is it possible to display superscripted characters (not only numbers) in the `alert()`,  `confirm()` or `prompt()` dialogue boxes in JavaScript?

Due to some reasons I need to insert a text:

*2 followed by superscripted 'n'*
*2^n*

Into JavaScript alert, confirm and prompt boxes. Fast google searching did help but not exactly I found a way to display superscripted numbers in dialogue boxes using Unicode *\u00B* character but it doesn't work with characters

```
alert('2\u00B2'); shows correctly 2^2
alert('2\u00Bn'); shows 2u00Bn
```

So the goal is to show a character superscripted not the number.

---

^ is used as Power and to show that next character is superscripted, just in case someone gets confused.

Comment: You can try this tool out and copy and paste any superscript characters into the alert string: https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's nothing magical about that character code - it just happens to be the one picked for the "Superscript two" character. There's also a "Superscript three" (`\u00B3`) (³) a "Superscript one" (`\00B9`) (¹), and a "Superscript Latin Small Letter N" (`\u207F`) (ⁿ). But if you need some other superscript, you're out of luck - `alert()` doesn't render HTML, so you're limited to the characters defined by Unicode.

You might be better off abandoning `alert()` entirely, and simulating a modal dialog within the page itself. Many libraries exist to provide this functionality already, including the excellent [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the jQuery UI. It's the best alternative to alert() by far - and allows for a consistent look across a site.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, there's no reliable way of getting superscript text into an alert box.  You could certainly do it on the page using the HTML `<sup>` tag, but in an alert box you're more limited.

The problem is: there is no "Unicode `\u00B`" character.  The character you're using is `\u00B2` (defined as "Superscript Two").  The fact that there's a two at the end is essentially coincidental.  The code point `\u00B1`, for example, is unrelated (it's the plus/minus sign).

There are a few other characters that have specific superscript versions in Unicode, which you can find in [this search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=superscript&preview=entity), but there aren't superscript versions of every letter.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode, or UTF-8 requires two pairs of characters, or four hexadecimal digits to make a character; `00B2` is recognized as "superscript 2" whereas `00Bn` is an invalid hexadecimal value. The superscript numbers 1-3 are: `00B9`, `00B2`, and `00B3`.

Unfortunately there is no magical superscript-prefix that will make the following character superscript. Only HTML `<sup>` can do that and, like Shog said, alert renders plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this code for generating unicode superscript integers:

```
const unicodeSuperscriptNumbers = [
    "\u2070",
    "\u00B9",
    "\u00B2",
    "\u00B3",
    "\u2074",
    "\u2075",
    "\u2076",
    "\u2077",
    "\u2078",
    "\u2079",
  ];

  function superscript(n: number) {
    if (!n) throw "no number provided";
    if (!Number.isInteger(n)) throw "We don't bother with non-integer superscripts for now";
    if (n < 0) return "\u207B" + superscript(n * -1);
    if (n > 10) return superscript(~~(n / 10)) + superscript(n % 10);
    return unicodeSuperscriptNumbers[n];
  }
```

If you need other characters as well, [this blog post](https://rupertshepherd.info/resource_pages/superscript-letters-in-unicode) lists most, but not all uppercase and lowercase superscript unicode letters, and it's relatively straightforward to extend the code above so it handles other characters.

Answer (score -1):

The npm package [numbers-to-superscript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numbers-to-superscript) converts all numbers in the specified string to superscript.

Might be an option here.